# relative path to deployed resources Tomcat 7

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I have the following project structure

[image]

Is it possible to access usersDev.json via relative path?
when I try with this 
`JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("src\\main\\webapp\\static\\usersDev.json"));`
It can not find the file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where you write `sonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("src\\main\\webapp\\static\\usersDev.json"));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never try to read resources from inside an application with `File`. Use `getResourceAsStream()` instead.